# How can i pull to refresh in flutter

Tags: flutter, pull-to-refresh, flutterwebviewplugin

webview_flutter: ^3.0.2 package using but no matter which pull to refresh package I add to the code, I could not run it, if you could help me, I would be very grateful. Thank you in advance.

```
  Future<void> _refreshWebView() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    await _webViewController.reload();
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }
```

```
return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _onBackPressed,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          toolbarHeight: 0,
          backgroundColor: APP_COLOR,
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: WebView(
                key: _webViewKey,
                initialUrl: _cachedUrl ?? WEB_VIEW_URL,
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                onPageFinished: (String url) {
                  setState(() {
                    _isLoading = false;
                  });
                },
                onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                  _webViewController = controller;
                },
              ),
            ),
            if (_isLoading) LinearProgressIndicator(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to achieve and how your code is supposed to trigger the **pull to refresh** functionality. Please elaborate. One of the standard Widgets that Flutter offers for this case is `RefreshIndicator`, maybe look more into it.

Answer (score 0):

**Please See This Reposetri :** https://github.com/RomitKatrodiya/in_app_webview

**Code**

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: HomePage(),
  ));
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final GlobalKey webViewKey = GlobalKey();

  InAppWebViewController? webViewController;

  InAppWebViewGroupOptions options = InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
      crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
        useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true,
        mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
      ),
      android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
        useHybridComposition: true,
      ),
      ios: IOSInAppWebViewOptions(
        allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
      ));

  late PullToRefreshController pullToRefreshController;
  String url = "";
  final urlController = TextEditingController();

  List bookMarksList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    pullToRefreshController = PullToRefreshController(
      options: PullToRefreshOptions(
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
      onRefresh: () async {
        if (Platform.isAndroid) {
          webViewController?.reload();
        } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
          webViewController?.loadUrl(
              urlRequest: URLRequest(url: await webViewController?.getUrl()));
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: TextField(
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      ),
                      controller: urlController,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.url,
                      onSubmitted: (value) {
                        var url = Uri.parse(value);
                        if (url.scheme.isEmpty) {
                          url = Uri.parse(
                              "https://www.google.com/search?q=$value");
                        }
                        webViewController?.loadUrl(
                            urlRequest: URLRequest(url: url));
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 12,
                  child: InAppWebView(
                    key: webViewKey,
                    initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
                      url: Uri.parse("https://www.google.co.in"),
                    ),
                    initialOptions: options,
                    pullToRefreshController: pullToRefreshController,
                    onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                      webViewController = controller;
                    },
                    onLoadStop: (controller, url) async {
                      pullToRefreshController.endRefreshing();
                      setState(() {
                        this.url = url.toString();
                        urlController.text = this.url;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      webViewController?.goBack();
                    },
                    mini: true,
                    child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new_outlined),
                  ),
                  FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      bookMarksList.add(url);
                      bookMarksList = bookMarksList.toSet().toList();
                    },
                    mini: true,
                    child: const Icon(Icons.bookmark_add_outlined),
                  ),
                  FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (BuildContext dialogContext) {
                          return AlertDialog(
                            title: const Center(child: Text('All BookMarks')),
                            content: SizedBox(
                              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.75,
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.75,
                              child: ListView.separated(
                                itemCount: bookMarksList.length,
                                itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                                  return ListTile(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                      webViewController?.loadUrl(
                                        urlRequest: URLRequest(
                                          url: Uri.parse(bookMarksList[i]),
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    },
                                    title: Text(
                                      bookMarksList[i],
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.blueAccent),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                                separatorBuilder: (context, i) {
                                  return const Divider(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    endIndent: 30,
                                    indent: 30,
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    },
                    mini: true,
                    child: const Icon(Icons.bookmark_border),
                  ),
                  FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      webViewController?.loadUrl(
                        urlRequest: URLRequest(
                          url: Uri.parse("https://www.google.co.in"),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    mini: true,
                    child: const Icon(Icons.home),
                  ),
                  FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      webViewController?.reload();
                    },
                    mini: true,
                    child: const Icon(Icons.refresh),
                  ),
                  FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      webViewController?.goForward();
                    },
                    mini: true,
                    child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios_sharp),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```